# Xamarin.IOS: Where can I find signing tab in info.plist?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an app that works in the IOS Simulator, but I can't build it to my iPhone. I'm using visual studio for Mac. When it builds, I get an error:

ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of ____ (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

Now, on the Xamarin.IOS documentation it says to open info.plist file, and go to the application tab, and go to the signing area. However this does exist.

This is what shows, nothing like what is shown in the docs.

[image]

I know how to set up provisioning in Xcode, but it doesn't seem to affect the build from visual studio. trying to build from Xcode fails with an error about no entry point.

I can't for the life of me find where to set up signing. I have added my appleID to the Preferences> Apple Developer Accounts, and it shows up. I have a paid developer account, that I have used to build stuff before using Unity/Xcode. This is my first time trying with Xamarin.IOS

How do I set up automatic signing? Where can I find the info.plist that they are talking about. It's clearly not the same one in my visual studio project.

Answer (score 1):

Of course... rebooting my computer solved it... Keeping this here, in case others run into this issue.

[image: itcrowd]